# Using a global variable inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use an already set global variable inside a function, but keep getting an error "Local variable "password" referenced before assigned". Is there something I'm missing to where it can't find the actual global variable?

```
password = ""
def random_characters(letters):
    add = random.choice(letters)
    password = password + add
letters_strong = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
for i in range(16):
    random_characters(letters_strong)
print(password)
```

Comment: You need to use the `global` keyword and "import" the globals into the function.

Comment: indentation. is the problem

Comment: @Carcigenicate Exactly how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @KariFox Lookup how to use the global keyword. Honestly, you should avoid using it when possible, but it's an option if you really need it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you.

Comment: This may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 2):

```
password = password + add
```

This creates a new local variable which shadows the global variable of the same name. To solve the problem, either use a different name for the local variable or pass a parameter. I strongly suggest the later.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to use the global variable though. I want the information to be stored there, not in a local variable to the function.

Comment: @KariFox Because explicitly passing in the information that's required for a fucntion to run is good habit. It makes it clear when reading the function what data is, and isn't relevant to the operation of the function. Plus, manipulating globals is a bad habit. It leads to a lot of problems down the road.

Comment: @KariFox I agree with the above comment. Global variables are considered a bad programming practice. You should definitely take the time to learn how to pass values as parameters and return values from functions. You can make a program with these tools that gives the same results as trying to do this with globals. And the program will be better designed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, global an assigned variable within a function is strongly recommended.

```
#coding: utf-8

_str = ""

def test(var):
    global _str
    _str += var
    return _str

test("output")
```

Answer (score 0):

use `global password` in the random_characters function.

So, for example,

```
password = ""
def random_characters(letters):
    global password
    add = random.choice(letters)
    password = password + add
letters_strong = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
for i in range(16):
    random_characters(letters_strong)
print(password)
```